# Como passar dados entre páginas?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estou tentando passar alguns valores entre páginas utilizando *ManagedBeans*, mas não está funcionando:

```java
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Chute {
    private Boolean chutar;
    //getters e setters...
}
```

Na primeira página XHTML tenho alguns `<p:commandButton/>`:

**pag1.xhtml**

```xhtml
<p:commandButton value="Chutar" action="#{Chute.setChutar(true)}" onstart="window.open('pag2.xhtml');"/>
<p:commandButton value="Passar" action="#{Chute.setChutar(false)}" onstart="window.open('pag2.xhtml');"/>
```

A segunda pega os dados enviados pela primeira:

**pag2.xhtml**

```xhtml
<p:panel rendered="#{Chute.chutar}">
    <p:outputLabel value="Chutou!"/>
</p:panel>
<p:panel rendered="#{Chute.chutar ? false : true}">
    <p:outputLabel value="Passou!"/>
</p:panel>
```

O problema é quando algum dos botões é clicado, a *pag2.xhtml* aparece em branco.
Como posso resolver? Existem outras abordagens?

Comment: Tente trocar de `onstart` para `oncomplete`. O problema é que está abrindo a nova janela antes do `action` ser completado.

Comment: @Wakim, deu no mesmo. O *ManagedBean* necessita de um construtor?

Comment: Se a página está em branco, é possível que haja algum erro no seu arquivo XHTML e o JSF não consegue renderizar a página.

Comment: Se eu coloco `rendered="true"` ou simplesmente removo o atributo, o painel aparece.

Comment: É só trocar o rendered por `#{not Chute.chutar}` ou `#{! Chute.chutar}` que funciona.

Comment: Deu alguma exceção (nos log's)? Tipo um `NullPoiterException` para o atributo `chutar`?

Comment: Está tudo limpo, nenhuma exceção.

Comment: Como os painéis da `pag2.xhtml` sabem de quem é a sessão? Quero dizer, ele não vai pegar uma sessão vazia? Pois não existe nada dizendo que é para pegar o objeto no qual o valor foi atribuído na `pag1.xhtml`.

Answer (score 1):

Tente mudar o seu `commandButton` para isso:

```
<p:commandButton value="Chutar" ajax="true" oncomplete="window.open('pag2.xhtml');">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{Chute.chutar}" value="true />
</p:commandButton>
```

Preciso testar, mas não sei se é possível chamar os métodos getters e setters diretamente como uma action do botão.

Comment: Renato, é possível sim, com uma `Method Expression` é possível chamar um método, apesar de ele ser um setter. Mas o `setPropertyActionListener` é interessante.

Comment: Não funcionou..